# Adding multiple sprite nodes to the scene using single function/method in swift

Tags: swift, nodes

Let's say I have 10 nodes, where all of the nodes are the dots image, which are `node1 thru node10`. I create `node1` as the following:

```
func createNode1() -> SKNode {
  let spriteNode = SKNode()
  spriteNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)/1.35, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)/1.32)
  let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dot_1")
  sprite.zPosition = 3.0
  sprite.name = "A1_Dot"
  spriteNode.addChild(sprite)      
  return spriteNode
}
```

I create the rest of nodes by creating 9 more functions, where next one would be as `func createNode2`etc, all the way up to 10 functions, where the only difference between them is node's name and its location. Basically each node has different location in the scene and of course different image name. Is there a way to load of the 10 nodes to the scene at once and manipulate node's locations at the time of use.? I'm looking for a way to load all 10 nodes to scene using a single function or method and assign node's positions within this same function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way is acceptable solution. Here are full details. In baseScene we create function `createNodes` and call that function in `didMoveToView` where `nodeA1` is given position and added to the scene as shown below.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
let nodeA1Pos = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)/1.5, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)/2.0)
    nodeA1 = createNodes(imageNamed: "dot_1", name: "A1_Dot", pos: nodeA1Pos)
    addChild(nodeA1)
}
```

Then in Level1Scene which is subclass of baseScene we just give a new position to `nodeA1` which will override position originally set in baseScene:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)
    nodeA1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)/1.3, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)/0.67)
}
```

This way of subclassing saves a lot of time and code as only one function is used to generate all common sprite nodes.

All thanks to crashoverride777 !!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a loop to iterate through an array of positions, and move your code that adds the node to the scene into the loop:

```
let positions = [CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)/1.35, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)/1.32), ... /*add your 9 other positions here*/]
positions.enumerate().forEach { (index, point) in
  let spriteNode = SKNode()
  spriteNode.position = point
  let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dot_\(index + 1)")
  sprite.zPosition = 3.0
  sprite.name = "A\(index + 1)_Dot"
  spriteNode.addChild(sprite)      

  // Add spriteNode to the scene here
}
```

Comment: How can I add this into function? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I think I figured it out! When you say in the comment above "// Add spriteNode to the scene here", did you mean the following:

self.addChild(spriteNode)

When I added to the scene this way, it seems that all nodes get loaded to the scene correctly but now when I try to use sprite name A\(index + 1)_Dot in my code, I get error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a loop as Jugale suggested or you could just pass the values you want into the method

For example

```
    func createNode1(imageNamed imageNamed: String, name: String, pos: CGPoint) -> SKNode {
        let spriteNode = SKNode()
        spriteNode.position = pos
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageNamed)
        sprite.zPosition = 3.0
       sprite.name = name
       spriteNode.addChild(sprite)      
        return spriteNode
   }
```

And now in your scene you can add the nodes like so

```
 let node1Pos = ...
 node1 = createNode1(imageNamed: "...", name: "A1_Dot", pos: node1Pos)


 let node2Pos = ...
 node2 = createNode1(imageNamed: "...", name: "A1_Dot", pos: node2Pos)
```

I am saying ImageNamed twice in the create Node function because when you pass stuff into functions Swift by default does not require the first description to be typed when calling the method. (see below)
So if would say imageNamed only once than you would call it like so.

```
  node1 = createNode1("...", pos: node1Pos)
```

Also your creating node function could be simplified, unless you specifically want to return a SKNode in the method.

```
   func createNode1(imageNamed imageNamed: String, name: String, pos: CGPoint) -> SKSpriteNode {

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageNamed)
        sprite.position = pos
        sprite.zPosition = 3.0
       sprite.name = name
       addChild(sprite)      
        return sprite
   }
```

Comment: Both ideas are good. You remember from other posting I am using baseScene to load all of my 10 nodes and leve1Scene thru level30Scene, where all 30 scenes are subclass of baseScene. Each leveXScene will place for example node1 to a different location on each of the 30 scenes. Would I still use this approach you mention here to do such setup for nodes in baseScene? Thanks.

Comment: Friend. Let me ask one more thing in terms of this approach here. Let say in baseScene I follow these steps to create node1 then in this same scene in didMoveToView I do 'let node1Pos = ...
 node1 = createNode1(imageNamed: "...", name: "A1_Dot", pos: node1Pos)'. The next step to use this same node will be Level1Scene which is subclass of baseScene. How would I handle node1 if only I have to change its position in Level1Scene subclass? I just need to confirm if my response to the solution below is correct. Thanks!!!

Comment: U asked me this before, you just change the position of the node to what you want (node1.position = ...) in the scene you want.

Comment: Yes I did. I was just lost little bit. Works great chief! Thanks!